# Group by clause is not giving me desired result in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I want the sum of pcurrentbalance and ptotal amount from my this query. But when I add these two columns in my group by clause then it didn't show me desired result. Please what is wrong in this query

```
select  
   a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo,
   (b.pCurrentBalance + b.pTotalAmt) as [OB] 
into #OB 
from   
     #user a 
left join  
     tbProcTransactions b on a.userid = b.puserid 
group by 
     a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo, pCurrentBalance, pTotalAmt
```

I am getting result for every user

```
userid  UserNM  UserPMobileNo   OB
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  118740
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  118793
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  118849
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  118968
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  118987
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  119072
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  119098
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  119217
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  119198
5   API_Ezy_User    9815765543  119360
```

Comment: Please show us some input data, and what you're currently getting with your query!

Comment: @marc_s check what i am getting in my result

Comment: OK - and what **do you** want from your query? You're grouping by columns that are not shown in the result - kinda makes it hard to see what's going on .... and without seeing the original source data, it's hard to know whether this is being grouped correctly or not ....

Comment: @marc_s as  you see i am getting the api_ezy_user's every result here Like this i am getting this result for every user. But Single Record from every user based on date or on whatever condition i use

Comment: That's because you're also grouping on the balance and amount fields, which has (relatively) unique values. Instead you probably want to sum those fields, so check out the answer given by @sashkello, and show us the SQL you have that gave you the error message you posted in the comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT  
   a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo,
   SUM(b.pCurrentBalance + b.pTotalAmt) AS [OB]
INTO #OB 
FROM   
     #user a 
LEFT JOIN
     tbProcTransactions b ON a.userid = b.puserid 
GROUP BY 
     a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo
```